# Prove that the solutions to the system of equations are integers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, systems-of-equations

> Let $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ and consider the system of equations below:
>   $$\begin{cases} y -2x-a =0\\
> y^2-xy+x^2-b=0\end{cases}
> $$
>   Prove that $x,y\in\mathbb{Q}$ implies $x,y\in\mathbb{Z}$.

I tried to do this by considering the term $b-a^2$ but got nowhere after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substitute $2x+a$ in the second equation.  After some simplification, you get:
$$3x^2+3ax+a^2-b=0\iff 3x(x+a)=b-a^2$$
Now write $x=\dfrac pq$ in irreducible form, $q>0$. The equation is equivalent to:
\begin{equation}3p(p+aq)=(b-a^2)q^2\end{equation}
Since $\gcd(p,q)=1$, hence $\gcd(q,p+aq)=1$, $q$ divides $3$.

But it is impossible that $q=3$ since this would imply $ p(p+aq)=3(b-a^2)$, and $3$ cannot divide $p$ nor $p+3a$.

This proves $x$, hence $y$, is an integer.

*Alternative proof* (by courtesy of PM 2Ring):

$q^2$ is coprime with $p$ and $p+aq$, hence by Gauß's lemma, it divides $3$. However the only square that divides $3$ is $1$, so that $x$ is an integer, whence $y$ is too.

Comment: Alternatively, $q^2$ divides $3p(p+aq)$, but if $q > 1$ then $q$ can't divide either of $p$ or $(p+aq)$, and the only square that divides 3 is 1.

Comment: Excellent! May I add it to my answer?

Comment: Sure! Although your answer is already excellent without it. :)

Comment: Yours is even shorter!